# Poisson solver on unstructured mesh

Tags: poisson, complexity

For the 2D Poisson equation, there exist on finite-difference mesh, some code taking $O(n \log(n))$ operations to solve it on a mesh with $n$ nodes. They rely on Fast Fourier Transform or Block Cyclic Reduction.

Is there anything as fast on unstructured meshes? I am afraid no, but fast solution of Poisson equation on unstructured meshes is a common problem. Any known efficient solution method?

Comment: Hi @MathieuDutourSikiric, and welcome to Scicomp!  Have you looked at this method: http://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/greengar/poiss2d.pdf

Comment: Should not finite element discretization with a multigrid solver for the resulting system of linear equation do it in $O(n)$?

Answer (score 5):

Multigrid solves the Poisson equation with complexity $O(n)$ which is the optimal possible complexity.